# Adding/removing/updating elements of navigation property collection using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Can you update (update meaning adding/removing/modifying entities within the collection) collection navigation properties in one go using EF Core?

Suppose you have a `Parent` class with several linked `Child` entities

```
public class Parent
{
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Child
{
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public long ParentId { get; set; }

  public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose you have a collection representing what the end result should look like, i.e. `List<Child> newChildren`. `newChildren` could have new elements, modified elements or elements that have been removed.

Obviously the first step would be to load the collection to ensure it's being tracked. The naive approach would be to simply assign `newChildren` to `Parent.Children`, but I've noticed EF can't quite figure out the exact updates that have taken place.

Children without ids are supposed to represent additions, children with existing ids should be updated, and children not found in the new collection should be removed, but I suppose that's not as straight-forward for the change tracker to identify.

How do you approach linked collection updates as efficiently as possible?

Comment: The question is unclear. What does `the exact updates that have taken place` mean? A DbContext is a Unit of Work that tracks changes to all reachable objects  and persists *all* of them when you call `SaveChanges` at the end of the UoW/Transaction. You don't have to call `Update` except to start tracking a new (detached) object

Comment: Also what does `efficiently` mean? The job of ORMs is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables and rows. That's more efficient for the programmer but sometimes won't be as performant as well-written SQL code. There are scenarios that ORMs just aren't built for, like importing and transforming lots of data, analyzing data or modifying a lot of data at once.